# Modulating from E Minor to C Minor

Tags: theory, modulation

I'm struggling to get from E Minor to a Bbsus chord. Once I get there, my modulation to C minor is good but I'm struggling to find something that moves me smoothly to the Bbsus. Any thoughts?

Comment: By the way Bb sus ***'what'*** - sus2/sus4 ??? - And which music style ? *'Jazzy'* with a lot of tensions allowed or more *'Classical'*, *'Pop'* ? - How many bars are available - slow or quickest possible modulation??? And above all *'for which instrument'* - solo or arrangement/orchestration?

Comment: @mramosch I think if it doesn't say 2 it's 4. In classical music the suspension always held a note from a previous chord that becomes fa->mi in the new chord.

Comment: In classical music there is also a suspension that holds a note from a previous chord that becomes re->mi in the new chord ;-) -> IV V I -> chords progression in C-major: C/F/ **A** -> D/G/ **A** -> D/G/ **B** -> E/G/ **C**

Comment: @mramosch nope that's called a _retardation_ not a suspension see http://www.musictheory.net/lessons/53

Comment: @Dom: I am referring to the analog phenomena that _@luserdroog calls a *'suspension'*... - just sus2 instead of sus4... - Or do you say this is a C(ret2)-chord instead of C(sus2)-chord ?

Comment: What genre is this?  if you just want to get from E minor to C minor you can do that through a diminished 7th.  It sounds like your real question is not getting to C minor but getting to Bb.

Comment: @mramosch Suppression only resolve downward in classically theory, retardation resolve upward which is why the default sus chord is a sus4 because this matches the traditional definition.

Comment: Suppression? Maybe we should bring *'depression*' into play... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you need to use Bbsus, but I can think of two other ways you can modulate.

- First, a way to modulate from E minor to C Minor is **chromatically**. Very simple, by flatting the E and B. Em is E,G,B and Ebm (III of C minor) is Eb,G,Bb. So, by this chromatic modulation, you find yourself to the C minor scale. *
- And secondly, while on E minor, you can play Em (i),  G(III) which G is the **V** of C minor and simply play Cm afterwards.

These two tonalities are a bit afar; E minor has one sharp while C minor has three flats, so the two aforementioned methods might sound a bit off, but they are the quickest way there.

A more smooth, but longer way would be to follow the circle of fifths leftwise. E minor to A minor to D minor to G minor to C minor, but that would take more time.

Since you like the sound of **Bb sus**, you can approach it chromatically. Similarly to the first way described above, you can play Em (E,G,B) and flat the E and B to Eb and Bb respectively, remove the G and you have the Bbsus chord. This might not be really smooth. Another way would be to play some other chord from the E minor scale that contains  either the note E or the note B.

*<sub>Generally, chromatic modulations are used to approach tonalities that far apart.</sub>

Comment: I don't know that I *need* the Bbsus, but it takes me where I go and helps build to the dramatic last verse. Plus I just like the sound of it :-) I'd like to keep it if I can get there smoothly, If not, I'll reconsider. But thanks for your suggestions...I'll try them out and see if I can get anything to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Tracey I added a way to use Bbsus, but it would be the smoothest; it will sound similar to the first way I posted

Comment: Thanks! I'll have more musical play-time tonight than I had last night, so i'll play around with that and see what I come up with.

Comment: Eb-Bb sounds more like an Eb5 chord instead of Bbsus without the fifth to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a chromatic modulation, if you don't want to use another key for the modulation.

This is maybe the simplest one.

[image]

Comment: Where's the B-flat sus4 chord? Are the Bs in the second chord supposed to be flat?

Comment: The main question is how to modulate from e-minor to c-minor. The user had a question about Bb-sus chord, which is not found in e-minor neither very useful as a modulation tool to c-minor. Therefore, my explanation offers a solution to modulation from e-minor to c-minor.

Comment: I guess it depends on what part of the question one sees as the essential part. I was keying off of: "...I'm struggling to find something that moves me smoothly to the Bbsus. Any thoughts?"

Comment: I agree. But Bb-sus is already Eb-major which is very far away from e-minor, and therefore very close to c-minor. If you need to have Bb-sus in e-minor and still not entering c-minor: it is very hard task. I would like to see how Tracey's progressions are moving and where it stops.

Comment: @ToddWilcox you're right, my issue was/is getting to the Bbsus from E minor. I don't have time to figure out how to insert an image of the section but the progression is i (Em) - i (Em7/D in bass) - iv6 (this is where I'm struggling...changing E to Eb helps, I'm just not sure it's enough) - Bb sus - Bb - Cm. Sorry if that's confusing, I couldn't figure out how to insert the image :-)

Comment: Bb (yours sus: Bb4/5) is so-called the polar chord, it is the farthest available chromatic chord in a scale in the tonal system, since it is found on a tritone. There are numerous possibilities to come to that chord, but the following point you have to keep in mind: P-chord is very far away. If you use it as an exception (Liszt, Dvorak) you must therefore to return back to your original key (e-min). But if you want to use it as a modulative-chord (use it to go to the another key) it will sound very unstable. Therefore, you need to reach c-minor (or Eb-major) before entering Bbsus4 (Bb4/5).

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on how long there is to make the transition, the harmonic rhythm within that time, and the demands of whatever might be happening melodically. That is to say: how many chords do you have time for, how long can you give a listener to adjust to the new harmony, and what restrictions does the melody place?

A general approach, though, might be to construct the progression in reverse. For discussion's sake, the simplest, smoothest way to get to the Bbsus is from a chord with two common tones. Here is a chart of options in which the non-common tone is within a semitone of its destination:

```
D-F-Bb    potentially gives away the game (= BbMaj)
E-F-Bb    very dissonant
Eb-E-Bb   very dissonant
Eb-Gb-Bb  Ebmin, the IV chord of the destination
Eb-F-A    basically F7, so the V chord of the destination
Eb-F-B    a more dissonant version of the F7 chord
```

This approach could be extended all the way back to the starting Emin.

Here are a couple of options that use that approach in part, but also rely on just messing around with what sounds good (to my ear).

Emin -> GMaj -> Gmin -> EbMaj -> EbMin -> Bbsus

```
X: 1
T: Emin -> Bbsus #1
K: none
M: none
L: 1/1
[EGB] [DGB] [DG_B] [_EG_B] [_E_G_B] [_EF_B]
```

Emin -> Eb+ -> GMaj -> AMaj -> Dmin -> F7 -> Bbsus

```
X: 1
T: Emin -> Bbsus #2
K: none
M: none
L: 1/1
[EGB] [_EGB] [DGB] [^CEA] [DFA] [_EFA] [_EF_B]
```

Answer (score -1):

By the way Bb sus ***'what'*** - sus2/sus4 ??? - And which music style ? *'Jazzy'* with a lot of tensions allowed or more *'Classical'*, *'Pop'* ? - How many bars are available - slow or quickest possible modulation??? And above all 'for which instrument' - solo or arrangement/orchestration?

- For a quicky from ***'Em'*** to ***'Cm'*** on the Piano just go *'Barbra Streisand'*:

> **| Em Em | F/G G || Cm(add9) |** ...

The highest notes also

> **| e e | f g || g |** ...

---

With the progression **IV/V - V - I** respectively **IV/V - V - i** (as seen from your new tonic) you can go absolutely everywhere in one bar. Major or Minor!  **Em** is already part of **C** - you just decide in the last moment to go *'minor'*... ;-)

Comment: Bb sus usually refers to sus 4

Comment: Yup, sus 4. It's a handbell arrangement of Kingsfold, more on the classical side. I'm moving from a somewhat contrapuntal 3-part texture to chords, so it's relatively thin. The Bbsus is where it builds before moving to c minor, I just wasn't happy with how I got there. The addition of an Eb to a previously a minor chord helped some, I'm still pondering if it was enough. But thanks to everyone who has weighed in for the help.